# Maven plugin for RAD 7.5.5

Tags: maven, rad

i have to migrate some project from Eclipse to RAD 7.5.5

Now i'm trying to install a maven plugin like i had on Eclipse, but i can't find it, i tried

```
http://repository.sonatype.org/content/sites/forge-sites/m2e
http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e-e34/
http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases
```

those sites that i found on web when i go for:

```
Help>Software Updates>Aviable Software>Add sites
```

gives to me "no repository found"

So i need a working repository to install Maven.
I found that this maven/rad version is very aged, so it can be hard to find now.

Any .zip file will be fine also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, RAD 7.5.x is not supported anymore by IBM (EOS dated on September 30, 2014), so my first advice is to move up to a newer version and I have the feeling that RAD includes Maven support since 8.5.1. Latest version out there is 9.1.1.

http://www-01.ibm.com/software/support/lifecycleapp/PLCDetail.wss?synkey=W170532D29019M02-L603472G19375Q17-M054243E02973V75

Second, honestly I don't recall which version of Eclipse is used in RAD 7.5.x. If it is older than Eclipse 3.6 then I don't think there is any integration for it. Try this repo

http://download.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/releases/juno/

Here is the M2E for WTP site in Eclipse Marketplace

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/maven-integration-eclipse-wtp-juno-0#.VIHEs10S1hg

Comment: Yes, i found that is about impossible made a maven build with a plugin with this version of RAD/WAS, i have to do it manually with an installed maven version.