# Maven for Eclipse IBM RAD 8.5

Tags: maven, ibm-rad

I use RAD 8.5 and I am trying to get maven plugin, however, when I go to Help -> Preferences I don't see a maven section. So I tried to go to IBM Installation Manager and it doesn't open. Do I have to install maven from Help -> install new software -> then http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases? Or is that unnecessary?

Answer (score 0):

Starting RAD 8.5.1 there's built-in support for Maven

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27024363#whatsnew_851_maven

Make sure you have this version and if so, use Installation Manager to update your installation with this new feature. If you don't have RAD 8.5.1 you can use steps provided in this thread to install it from Eclipse Marketplace, although I can't really assure you it will work.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27318541/2593668

Hope this helps